# How to place 2 div side by side (alternative solution)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I'm trying to accomplish something as simple as putting to div's side by side. The thing is I'm very capable in CSS, however the solutions I'm trying to use do not work as intended, here is the problem.

I'ved used: (so both divs is laying side by side)

> display: block;
>  float: left;
>  margin-right: 15px;

And it work flawlessly **LOCALLY**, the thing is I'm creating this as a template solution which the html & css are being build into a system and after that will be generated to a javascript tag. The javascript tag will then be thrown into different websites and therefore, it's very important it acts alike in all browsers.

Then i tryed position the div (the one laying on the side) to: absolute and using left to position it on the side... That don't work either because its absolute to where the tag is implemented, meaning it would show up different places depending which site the tag is implemented.

So my question is, is there a way i can use either css or javascript so my divs are side by side no matter where i implement the tag?

Below is my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Sidekick</title>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/sidekick.js"></script>      
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
    </head>
        <body>  
        <div class="eas_sidekick_divs">     
            <div id="eas_sidekick">
                <div class="eas_sidekick_open">x</div>
            </div>
            <div id="eas_sidekick_container"></div>             
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.eas_sidekick_divs div
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right:15px;  
}

#eas_sidekick
{
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    background: #ccc;
}

#eas_sidekick_container
{   
    width: 850px;
    height:600px;
    background: #ccc;           
}
```

This solution works locally as said, but not after i generate this to a tag. You can see the example here: 
http://yoursource.eu/stuff/Templates/sidekick/300x250/javascript.html

Look in the different browsers like: IE & Chrome and see the difference and how weird it acts.

Click on the button of the little banner to the right stating: "exiting me" and you'll see the div expand, the expanded div is the one i want to position to right at all times.

Hope u can help me out! :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify display block on a DIV as that is the default state. What do you mean by how weirdly it acts. Your link looks the same to me in IE, FF & Chrome. On your demo page the <style> tag should be reloacted to within the HEAD tag. Where you have it placed is invalid. You also don't have a valid DOCTYPE declared.

Comment: I excluded the rest of the html for a easy view. There is a doctype stated. In "weird" I mean it should open to the right side of my content and expand instead of below. The one I'm talking about incase i did a bad description im talking about the little banner to the right when u click on it a div expand, and its THAT div that expand i want to position to the right of the content.

Comment: 'Click on the button of the little banner to the right stating: "exiting me" and you'll see the div expand, the expanded div is the one i want to position to right right at all times.'

Comment: It sinmply seems too wide to float to the right of those elements hence why it goes below them.

Comment: However the width of my expanding div needs to be wider than the other div. Any work arounds in javascript i can use? :)

Comment: I'd suggest having it appear centered on the page and above the other DIVs. If you don;t have the space for it to appear on the right side and you can't change the width then you don't have many options.

Comment: Don't have time for that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out myself a javascript solution for fixing my issue.

I've used position absolute to fix it in all browsers and then created a javascript that depending on the width of the site, it position itself always 10 pixels to the right of my container.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var cssWidth = 1024;
    var cssPos = 10;

    $("#eas_sidekick_container").hide();
    $("#eas_sidekick_container").css(
    {
        width: '0px',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0px',
        left: cssWidth + cssPos
    });

 $(".eas_sidekick_open").click(
            function() {
                $("#eas_sidekick_container").show();
            $("#eas_sidekick_container").animate({
                width: '850px'              
            });
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: '850'
            });
    });

 $(".eas_sidekick_close").click(
            function() {
                $("#eas_sidekick_container").animate({
            width: '0px'
            });
            setTimeout( function(){
                $("#eas_sidekick_container").css(
                    'display' , 'none' 
                );
            }, 350);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block; or display:block; both will work but as you mention "#eas_sidekick_container" width should be equal or should not exceed with parent Element width   please correct "#eas_sidekick_container" width.

Here is the corrected code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
   .eas_sidekick_divs div
    {        
        float: left;
        margin-right:15px;  
    }

  #eas_sidekick
  {
      width:300px;
      height:600px;
      background: #ccc;
  }

  #eas_sidekick_container
  {   
      width: 300px;
      height:600px;
      background: #ccc;           
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="eas_sidekick_divs">     
   <div id="eas_sidekick">
      <div class="eas_sidekick_open">x</div>
   </div>
   <div id="eas_sidekick_container"></div>              
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But i need the width of the 'eas_sidekick_container' to be 850. Any other work arounds? maybe in js?